# In R: How to store the list ouputs of a function in the same list when im in a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I have a column in a dataframe "q$Kegg" where each row is a entrie for the function "keggGet()", this function have a limit of max 10 entries each time it run, then i decided use a loop for.
My dataframe "q" look like:

```
col1 col2     Kegg       col4 col5
data  .   ath:AT3G05640   .   data
data  .   ath:AT1G53520   .   data
data  .   ath:AT3G10870   .   data
data  .   ath:AT5G02770   .   data
```

The ouput of this function is a list. Example for

`query<-keggGet("ath:AT3G05640")`
[ouput image in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14x5x.jpg)

Example of raw ouput

```
> keggGet("ath:AT3G05640")

[[1]]
[[1]]$ENTRY
        CDS 
"AT3G05640" 

[[1]]$DEFINITION
[1] "(RefSeq) Protein phosphatase 2C family protein"

[[1]]$ORGANISM
                                 ath 
"Arabidopsis thaliana (thale cress)" 

[[1]]$POSITION
[1] "3"

[[1]]$MOTIF
[1] "Pfam: PP2C SpoIIE PP2C_2"

[[1]]$DBLINKS
[1] "NCBI-GeneID: 819731"          "NCBI-ProteinID: NP_001326841" "MIPS: AT3G05640.1"           
[4] "TAIR: AT3G05640"              "UniProt: Q9M9W9"             

[[1]]$AASEQ
  A AAStringSet instance of length 1
    width seq
[1]   358 MGHFSSMFNGIARSFSIKKAKNINSSKSYAKEATDEMAREAK...AAKRLVQQAVRAWNRKRRGIAMDDISAVCLFFHSSSSSPSL

[[1]]$NTSEQ
  A DNAStringSet instance of length 1
    width seq
[1]  1077 ATGGGACATTTCTCTTCCATGTTCAACGGTATAGCTAGATCC...GCCTCTTCTTCCATTCTTCATCGTCGTCGCCATCTCTATAG
```

If i have to do this step by step it will look like:

```
query<-keggGet(c("ath:AT3G05640","ath:AT1G53520",.....)) 
#up to 10 entries each run for my 8000 entries and naming query2, query3,...
#because i don't know how to add the new results to "query" without overwriting.
```

Then i want to make a loop where each result is stored in query as if i run the fuction for all my entries (can't do that because 10 limit). Until now i have:

```
for (k in q$Kegg) 
{
  query<-keggGet(k)
}
```

How i can add each ouput of the fuction to the ouput list "query"?

Comment: Can you provide your data or an example so it is more reproducible? I see you have a list of length 1 - would it thus be okay to have a dataframe with the result from each row in one row of the dataframe?

Comment: `query <- list(); for (k in seq_along(q$Kegg) )
{
  query[k] <- keggGet (q$Kegg[k] )
}`

Comment: @CareyCaginalp example data added. After i get all the ouputs i really want to convert the full list to a proper dataframe where each row is the ouput of a entrie and is distributed in columns so is easy to read, but that will be another different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query <- list();
for (k in seq_along(q$Kegg) ) {   query[k] <- keggGet (q$Kegg[k] ) }
```

The paradigm of initializing an empty list object and then iterating over the integer vector returned by `seq_along` to successively assign values to populate that list to the same length is bog-standard R coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` :

```
query <- lapply(q$Kegg, keggGet)
```